# Удивительно! может мне кто-нибудь скажет, что это?

Tags: php, mysql

делаю запрос для каждого выбранного checkbox

```
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value){

    $t='SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="'.$value.'"';
        echo $t;//вывод для просмотра запроса
    $mysql_afhgahf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id='".$value."'");
    $mysql_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_afhgahf);
    echo $mysql_fetch['description']."<br />";
                    }
```

обычные запросы, казалось бы, только при выборе, например, всех чеков, он выдает ошибку, и ошибки вылетают непонятно из за чего! Смысл

```
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="19"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28

SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="18"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28

SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="17"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28

SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="16"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28

SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="20"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28

SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="21"
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in L:\home\localhost\www\versal_anapa.ru\admin\catalog\operations.php on line 28
```

вот эти вот ошибки!
кто мне скажет?

Comment: запрос не удался, смотрите в документации как получить ошибку mysql. ну и так - на всякий случай, то что вы используете как аргумент для mysql_query() и то что в echo - разные строки. что вас останавливает от использования $t = непонятно.

Comment: Какой хороший sql injection на нас смотрит из вашего кода! Хоть сейчас в учебник.

Comment: все запросы правильные... нет ошибок, в переменной $t находится запрос, что используется в выборке... только он ругается непонятно на что! порой он выводит такие ошибки, а так все работает... мне не понятно, почему он дает сбой, ведь все правильно?!?!?

Comment: Тебе же написали, проверить:
if($mysql_afhgahf) 
{
...
}
else 
{ 
 print mysql_error(); 
}

Если есть ошибка, то она выведется.

Comment: @tagir, запрос вернет либо необходимый ресурс, либо false. У вас в коде вообще не предусмотрен возврат false. Оттуда и ошибка (это если в краткой перспективе).

Comment: дело в том, что я уже проверял на выполнение $mysql_afhgahf, только он возвращает только TRUE, false - нет, а нужные элементы из БД не выдергивает, пишет ошибка, что описывал раньше...

Comment: @lightcyber, он уже сделал var_dump($_POST[check]) своеобразно, и судя по выводу, там числа

Comment: @tagir, mysql\_query **не может** возвращать true при select-запросе. [Пруф](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверку ошибок в коде тоже пока никто не отменял! Да еще и откуда уверенность, что $value содержит число, а не попытку хакнуть ваш сайт??

```
$t='SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id="'.$value.'"';
        echo $t;//вывод для просмотра запроса
$mysql_afhgahf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id='".$value."'") or die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($mysql_afhgahf) == 0) {
    echo "Ничего не найдено";
    continue;
}
$mysql_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($mysql_afhgahf);
echo $mysql_fetch['description']."<br />";
```

Comment: `$queryTemplate = 'SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE id = :id';
foreach($_POST['check'] as $id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    if ($id === 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Security breach attempt, halting');
    }
    $query = str_replace(':id', $id, $queryTemplate);
    $queryResult = mysql_query($query);
    if ($queryResult && mysql_num_rows($queryResult) !== 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);
        echo $row['description'];
     }
}`